# Why is the document returning null even though I already subscribed to the collection (Meteor)?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a `Books` and `Chapters` collection. Self-explanatory: A book can have many chapters.

**subscriptions.js:**

```
Meteor.publish("singleChapter", function(id) {
  return Chapters.find(id);
});
```

**book_page.js:**

```
Template.bookPage.helpers({
  chapters: function() {
    Chapters.find({
      bookId: this._id
    }, {
      sort: {
        position: 1
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**book_page.html:**

```
<template name="bookPage">
  <div class="chapter-list hidden">
    <div class="chapter-items">
    {{#each chapters}}
      {{> chapterItem}}
    {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**chapter_item.html:**

```
<template name="chapterItem">
  <div class="chapter clearfix">
    <div class="chapter-arrows">
      <a class="delete-current-chapter" href="javascript:;">X</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Right now, I'm trying to get the current chapter item in `chapter_item.js`:

```
Meteor.subscribe("singleChapter", this._id); // even tried this but didn't work

Template.chapterItem.events({
  "click .delete-current-chapter": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentChapter = Chapters.find(this._id);
  }
});
```

But when I do

```
console.log(currentChapter);
```

I get `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick comment: `href="javascript:;"`... People have been lynched for less than that! =p

Answer (score 1):

**TL/DR** - skip to 3 as it's probably most relevant, but I've included the rest for completeness.

1. I assume you're putting the `console.log...` line in the `"click .delete-current-chapter"` callback?  The `currentChapter` variable is going to be local to that function, so you won't get anything by entering that in the console.  Apologies if that's obvious, but it's not clear that you're not doing this from the question.
2. Even in the callback, `currentChapter` is going to be a cursor, not a document or array of documents.  Use `findOne` to return a single doc (or null), or `find(query).fetch()` to return an array (which in this case should probably be just one doc).
3. Where and when are you trying to subscribe to `singleChapter`?  If it's in the callback, you have to bear in mind that this isn't a reactive function.  This means that you'll subscribe (once you know the `_id` to which to subscribe), but immediately return `currentChapter` before the collection is actually ready (and thus doesn't have anything in it).  In this case, the callback *won't* rerun once the collection is ready as event handlers aren't reactive.

   The easiest way to resolve this would be to use the [`onReady` callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) when you subscribe, and set `currentChapter` in there.  The alternative would be a self-stopping `Tracker.autorun` in the event handler, but this seems like overkill.
4. As a final point, you need to be a bit careful about subscriptions with this sort of setup, as you can easily accumulate dozens and dozens of them per client, with none of the automatic subscription stopping that Iron Router provides.  Given this use case, it's probably preferable to stop the subscription as soon as your callback has run and the item in question has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Is your publish function working? Perhaps Mongo has a feature that I'm not aware of, but I'd expect you need to include `{_id:id}`, not just (id).

`Meteor.publish('singleChapter', function(id){
        return Chapters.find({_id: id});
    });`